# button to export tables to excel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have few pages of tables, and I have created a button to export the table to excel. my problem is that it only export the current page of table that in at and not all the pages? can anyone help me out?

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            //To Export all pages
            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;


            GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                row.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you please show me your effort

Comment: Share your code so that we can update.

Comment: ok wait guys sending

Comment: guys, it's ok. have solved the problem